# Nginx configuration for assets files with different port and subdomain

Tags: http, nginx

I want to serve my asset files  with nginx.  The ngnix server listen port such as 8000 ( it must be different from 80) and I want to access the files via subdomain like assets.mydomain.com.

I try to configure but I can't  do that. How should I configure ? Thanks your answers.

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

}
# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name assets.localhost;

    location /assets/ {
                root /var/www/html/skytrip/assets
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should be more specific about the problem that you're having. What behaviour did you expect from that configuration? What actually happened? Was there an error? Can you send the last lines of your log files? Etc.

Did you forget the semi-colon after the root directive?